# Need to display total values in the footer in ag-grid using angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am currently implementing ag-grid in my angular 7 application. I need to include the footer for each group which I have achieved. I would now need to display the Total of EMV(USD) and Percent Column like the screenshot below. The row should be blank for each cell except for the two columns mentioned and the totals should be displayed

[image]

Component

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AllocationsService } from '../services/allocations.service';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/gridOptions';
import { Comparator } from '../utilities/comparator';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';


@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-allocations',
    templateUrl: './allocations.component.html'
})


export class AllocationsComponent implements OnInit {

    private Error: string;
    public evalDate: Date;
    private _evalDate: Date;
    public AllocationDetails: any;
    private _ManagerStrategyId: number;
    public GridOptions: GridOptions;
    windowHeight: any;
    offset: number;
    ngZone: any;
    router: any;
    Comparator: Comparator;
    Route: any;

    public get ManagerStrategyId(): number {
        return this._ManagerStrategyId;
    }


    @Input()
    public set ManagerStrategyId(value: number) {
        this._ManagerStrategyId = value;
    }


    constructor(private allocationsService: AllocationsService, private comparator: Comparator,
                private zone: NgZone, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.Comparator = comparator;
        this.Route = route;

        window.onresize = (e) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight - this.offset;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (!this.GridOptions || !this.GridOptions.api) {
                        return;
                    }
                    this.GridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                }, 500, true);
            });
        };
    }

    private FormattedDate(dateToFormat: Date): string {
        return formatDate(dateToFormat, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en');
    }


    get MissingProductKeys() {
        const  missingProductsTypesNames = this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.flat().map(({ProductType}) => ProductType);
        const  uniqueProductTypeNames = new Set(missingProductsTypesNames);
        return  Array.from(uniqueProductTypeNames.values());
    }

    setGridOptions() {
        this.GridOptions = {
            columnDefs: this.getColumns(),
            enableFilter: true,
             treeData: true,
            enableColResize: true,
            animateRows: true,
            groupDefaultExpanded: 1,
            enableSorting: true,
            suppressCellSelection: true,
            groupIncludeFooter: true,
            getDataPath: function (data) {
                return data.Hierarchy;
            },
            onGridReady: e => {
                if (!e || !e.api) {
                    return;
                }
                e.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                this.setDefaultSortOrder();
            },
            getRowStyle: (params) => {
                if (params.node.level === 0) {
                    return { 'background-color': '#FCE7D7' };
                }
            },

            autoGroupColumnDef: {
                headerName: 'Manager Strategy', width: 300,
                valueFormatter: uniqueColumn
            },

        };
        function uniqueColumn(params) {

        const startIndex = params.value.indexOf('#');
        if (startIndex === -1) { return params.value; }

        const endIndex = params.value.length;
        return params.value.replace(params.value.substring(startIndex, endIndex), '');

    }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.evalDate = new Date();
        this.setGridOptions();
        this.getAllocationsDetails(this.FormattedDate(this.evalDate));

    }

     getAllocationsDetails(evalDate: string) {
        if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
            this.initGrid();
           //this.GridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();
            this.allocationsService.getAllocationsDetails(this.ManagerStrategyId, evalDate)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.AllocationDetails = data;
                    this.GridOptions.rowData = this.AllocationDetails.ManagerAllocations;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      //  this.GridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
                    }, 100, true);
                },
                    err => {
                        this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                    },
                    () => {
                      //  this.GridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
                    });
        }
    }


    public evalDateChanged(value: Date): void {
        this.getAllocationsDetails(this.FormattedDate((value)));
    }

    GridHeight() {
        if (!this.windowHeight) {
            this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight - this.offset + 10;
        }
        return this.windowHeight;
    }


    setDefaultSortOrder() {
        const defaultSortModel = [
            { colId: 'ManagerStrategyName', sort: 'asc' },
            { colId: 'ManagerFundName', sort: 'asc' }
        ];
        this.GridOptions.api.setSortModel(defaultSortModel);
    }

    private initGrid() {
        const self = this;
    }



    private getColumns(): Array<any> {
        const self = this;
        const definition = [
            { headerName: 'Date', field: 'EvalDate', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm ID', field: 'FirmID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy ID', field: 'FirmName', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm', field: 'ManagerStrategyID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy', field: 'ManagerStrategyName' , hide: false },
            { headerName: 'Fund ID', field: 'ManagerFundID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Fund', field: 'ManagerFundName' },
            { headerName: 'Portfolio', field: 'ProductName' },
            { headerName: 'As Of', field: 'EvalDate',   cellRenderer: (data) => {
                return data.value ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
             } },
            { headerName: 'EMV (USD)', field: 'UsdEmv',  valueFormatter: currencyFormatter },
            { headerName: 'Percent', field: 'GroupPercent', valueFormatter: formatPercent },





        ];
        function currencyFormatter(params) {
            if (!isNaN(params.value)) {
            return '$' + formatNumber(params.value);
            }
        }

        function formatNumber(number) {
            // this puts commas into the number eg 1000 goes to 1,000,
             return Math.floor(number).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
        }

        function formatPercent(number) {
            if (!isNaN(number.value)) {
            return (number.value * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
            }
        }
        return definition;
    }
}
```

New code based on proposed answer

```
private getColumns(): Array<any> {
        const self = this;
        const definition = [
            { headerName: 'Date', field: 'EvalDate', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm ID', field: 'FirmID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy ID', field: 'FirmName', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm', field: 'ManagerStrategyID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy', field: 'ManagerStrategyName', hide: false },
            { headerName: 'Fund ID', field: 'ManagerFundID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Fund', field: 'ManagerFundName' },
            { headerName: 'Portfolio', field: 'ProductName' },
            {
                headerName: 'As Of', field: 'EvalDate', cellRenderer: (data) => {
                    return data.value ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
                }
            },
            {
                headerName: 'EMV (USD)', field: 'UsdEmv', valueFormatter: this.currencyFormatter,
                cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
                aggFunc: 'sum',
                cellRendererParams: {
                    footerValueGetter: (params) =>   params.value

                }
            },
            {
                headerName: 'Percent', field: 'GroupPercent', valueFormatter: this.formatPercent,
                cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
                aggFunc: 'sum',
                cellRendererParams: {
                    footerValueGetter: (params) => params.value
                }
            }
        ];
        return definition;
    }


    currencyFormatter(number) {
        // this puts commas into the number eg 1000 goes to 1,000,
        if (!isNaN(number.value)) {
        number = Math.floor(number.value).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
        number = number === '0' ? '0.00' : number;
        return '$' + number;
        }
    }

     formatPercent(number) {
        if (!isNaN(number.value)) {
            return (number.value * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        }
    }
```

New Screenshot

[image]

Comment: and pls stop sharing the screenshots, share plinkr\stackblitz url instead where everyone can test ur approach

Answer (score 5):

I've made it in a different way:

```
let pinnedBottomData = this.generatePinnedBottomData();
this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData([pinnedBottomData]);

generatePinnedBottomData(){
    // generate a row-data with null values
    let result = {};

    this.gridColumnApi.getAllGridColumns().forEach(item => {
        result[item.colId] = null;
    });
    return this.calculatePinnedBottomData(result);
}

calculatePinnedBottomData(target:any){
    //list of columns for aggregation
    let columnsWithAggregation = ['age']
    columnsWithAggregation.forEach(element => {
        this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter((rowNode: RowNode) => {
            if (rowNode.data[element])
                target[element] += Number(rowNode.data[element].toFixed(2));
        });
        if (target[element])
            target[element] = `Age Sum: ${target[element].toFixed(2)}`;
    })
    return target;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/C6mUcz0kIlj8fcyJjkAn?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For each column definition, you can pass an extra parameter to change how the column is rendered

```
cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
cellRendererParams: {
    footerValueGetter: (params) => 'Text (' + params.value + ')'
},
aggFunc: "sum"
```

where params.value is the column name

Comment: Where do I need to add this ? In the column definition setgridOptions method . Also how will it know that total has to be added for specific column

Comment: Should  be in the definition array in getColumns function, look at the updated answer for the second  question.

Comment: [more details](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#grouping-footers) about grouping footer, but I'd say @Tom, you have to look up into [pinned rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/) - it's much easier than aligned grid (as a footer) or as `footerValueGetter` - cuz its not enought

Comment: I did tried the above in my getColumns function and it displays Text(0)

Comment: Does the grid have the ability to total the rows for that column by using some inbuilt function

Comment: Get a compile time error when i add aggFunc: "sum". Cannot find the name aggFunc

Comment: Can you  add  the new code used? It is being used on one of the examples without a problem [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aggregation/)

Comment: Hi  I have somehow managed to get the totals but as you can see I have an issue here . The total is showing both in the header and footer. The header is showing the correct value using the respective functions but the footer isnt. I need to display the it only in the footer.

Comment: Can you create a project on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) and share it, so i can test it?

Comment: I have added the stackblitz however the grid isnt showing up probably due to license As there are no errors. It had happen to me in the local envirornment as well but after applying lincekey it worked How would you test it. Here is the link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnddf9

Comment: I have somehow tried to populate the data but it doesnt seem to be properly formatted . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6rqpz

Answer (score 2):

Ag Grid has attributes something called groupIncludeFooter, groupIncludeTotalFooter. You can refer it on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#grouping-footers

```
  <ag-grid-angular
      ...
      [groupIncludeFooter]="true"
      [groupIncludeTotalFooter]="true"
      ...
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/pBG3to7sebxDC7Yq

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: How do we apply the aggFunc it on load of the grid when there is no grouping applied, the row appears blank.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this earlier on, whereby you can make use of [aligned grids as footer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/). They have included an example, so you should refer to it.

A summary, on the component.html, you have to include the `ag-grid-angular` component twice on your template, each of them with its own individual `gridOptions` properties

```
<ag-grid-angular #topGrid [gridOptions]="topOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
<ag-grid-angular #bottomGrid [gridOptions]="bottomOptions".... ></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts, you will define your `columnDefs` as usual, as well as the respective `gridOptions`.

As mentioned on the example on the link above, aligning the two grids will give you a footer grid which is vertically aligned to your main grid. This way, you can display the total value, etc on that footer.